# is it possible to completely vanish the form not only its fields after a successful submission?

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I want to completely vanish the form, not only its fields after a successful submission.
is there a function or sumthing to do so?

Comment: Show some code to exemplify your current progress. It would help better understand your requirement. Also define what do you mean by *vanish*? You want the form to be removed from the DOM or just hide it?

Comment: you can do this by `document.getElementById("formid").reset();`

Comment: or place form in a div and than `$("div id or class").html();` will remove form or `$("class or id of from ").remove();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you with "vanish" mean delete the form, you could do something like this with plain JavaScript:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("idOfForm");
elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
```

Since you have a jquery-ajax tag on the question, I guess you use jQuery. In that case you could do the same thing like so:

```
$("#idOfForm").remove();
```

**Or**, if you just want to hide the form, but keep it in the DOM:

```
$("#idOfForm").hide();
```

Comment: @ankitaalung My pleasure! As you are new to StackOverflow, consider marking the answer that was most useful to you as the accepted answer, by clicking the checkmark to the left of that answer. You can read more about accepting answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

no sure what you meant by vanish .. but i think [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)..is what u need

> Hide the matched elements.

```
 $('#yourFormID').hide();
```

**OR**

[remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

> Remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

```
 $('#yourFormID').remove();
```